# TextView paints text garbled on update and scroll

Tags: android

I created a test android app which listens to a topic on a RabbitMQ server and shows the messages in a textview.

All works fine except that on every new message that is added to the 'output' textview the new text is painted over the old text. The same happens when I scroll, as can be seen in the second image. When the app goes to the background and is activated again, then the text is displayed normal again (see picture 1).

[image: normal output]

[image: garbled output]

My layout is really simple: what am I doing wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="60dp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connection status" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Received messages:" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</ScrollView>
```

Here is where I handle a new message coming in:

```
final Handler myViewUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
    // @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case NEWSTATUS: 
            status.setText((String) msg.obj);
            status.invalidate();
            //also add to output
        case NEWMESSAGE:
            String oldText= (String) output.getText();
            output.setText("");

            String newText = DateUtil.getClockTimeMillis()+" "+(String) msg.obj+"\n"+oldText;

            output.setText(newText);
            output.invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no case for:" + msg.arg1);
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same exact problem. In my case this is what happened and how I worked it out:

- first I've added second activity with full screen attributes (via the
  eclipse wizard)
- then i decided not to use that fancy animated full screen, so i
  edited the layout XML file and changed it to normal relative view.
- the app manifest file indicated that this activity is still using the
  full screen theme.
- I've deleted those lines and...the problem is solved.

if you set the full screen theme for the layout try to change it to app main theme.

Comment: I did exactly as you describe, first generate a fullscreen activity, than change to normal and indeed style was still fullscreen. Unfortunatly I can not test the code anymore as the project is closed (we did not need that test code anymore). Still I think you are right in yoiur analysis and solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove invalidate() method calls from all cases, if it doesn't solve the issue, in your xml put this in TextView's(id=output) of ScrollView attribute

```
 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried both seperate and together: alas it does not resolve my problem. I am puzzeled by this problem, in my other apps I never hasd something like this. This should be simple right?

Comment: yeah normally you shouldn't have this problem. Another issue that might cause this is, maybe your handler refreshing too much so your device can't reach the frequency of Handler, try to decrease the frequency of Handler by below code.

Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
  {
   
   public void run() 
   { 
// put your update code here
 }}, 5000(-or another number-);  it means your handler will refresh at each 5000 msec, you can modify it if it seems too fast/slow.

Comment: This will not work for me as I use the content of textview as my cache (maybe that is my problem)? -> String newText = DateUtil.getClockTimeMillis()+" "+(String) msg.obj+"\n"+oldText;

Comment: hımm maybe. Another way can be increasing cache memory size allocated for your application.

Comment: ok tried a seperate String field to cache the text, does not help :( I do not think the handler is the problem as it occurs on scrolling to: something must be wrong in how I declare my TextView

Comment: how do you increasing cache memory size? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: ok try this, instead of textview in scrollview add a listview in scroll view and on your code add new textview item to this listview every time you get an update, i guess this should work out